# Unable to communicate with web service using Apache Axis2

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I have a web service hosted on a Windows Server which I can connect to with .net code and I am trying to gain access using Apache Axis2.  I have been working with clj-soap which isn't being maintained but appears moderately stable.

Connecting to the service endpoint works ie (soap/client-fn service-address) but whenever I attempt to call a function Axis2 gives this exception:

```
org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender sendViaPost
Unable to sendViaPost to url[MY-URL]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found
```

Through some googling I've ran across things like [this](http://robaustin.wikidot.com/axis), which tells me that Windows is requiring some authentication or proxy configuration.  I'm not sure what kind of authentication the server requires.  The .net code does not authenticate with a password, so I am at a loss.

I'm looking for some help determining what information to give Axis2 to pass along to the server so my program can communicate with the web service.

The C# code is provided below, as a reference.  It uses the ServiceModel library.

```
class Program {
    private static MyService CreateServiceChannel () {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding ( BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport );
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 204003200;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress ( "https://...service.svc" );
        ChannelFactory<MyService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService> ( binding, address );
        MyService channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel ();
        return channel;
    }

    static void Main ( string[] args ) {
        Console.WriteLine ( CreateMyChannel ().CallFunction ( 1 ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: `404 Error: Not Found` The simplest explanation is that your URL is incorrect.

Comment: That makes sense.  When I call [this function](http://bit.ly/1EyKam0), is the invalid URL coming from the client object, or the xml payload eg `client.sendRecieve("CallFunction", "<xml-payload>...</xml-payload>")`? Trying to narrow down where I should be investigating.  The payload contains the namespace URL, but I am surprised it doesn't contain the complete input/output action URL(s).

Comment: The presumably incorrect URL is the one that appears in the error as `url[MY-URL]`. I'd expect this is also the one you set as the endpoint address. Namespace URLs aren't intended to actually be called.

Comment: Thanks.  Based on that description I I believe the program is not doing everything necessary to consume a WCF service.